# How to make if statements with strings? in c++

Tags: c++

i have been working on a project that imitates the software of a cash register.
i made a list of products that you could buy and for you to buy you input the product's name. Now my problem appears here, i wanted to associate somehow the name of the product with the price.
how can i do that?

```
//i wanted this in my code
    int appleprice

if(product == apple(for example))
{
cout << appleprice;
}


//how my code is
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string Pproduct;
    int Pquantity;
    double Wallet = rand() %38217;
    int Apple = 0.99; 

    cout <<"\n\nWelcome to the A&L\n";
    cout <<"you have " << Wallet << "eur on your account\n";
    cout <<"Here is the list of products\n\n\n\n";
    cout <<"****************************************\n";
    cout <<"*             LIST OF PRODUCTS         *\n";
    cout <<"*                                      *\n";
    cout <<"*                                      *\n";
    cout <<"* Apple---------------------------0.99 *\n";
    cout <<"* Bread---------------------------0.66 *\n";
    cout <<"* Cake----------------------------1.80 *\n";
    cout <<"* Cheese--------------------------1.90 *\n";
    cout <<"* Chicken-------------------------6.30 *\n";
    cout <<"* Salad---------------------------1.90 *\n";
    cout <<"* Salmon--------------------------4.20 *\n";
    cout <<"* Port Wine-----------------------5.90 *\n";
    cout <<"* Beer----------------------------2.00 *\n";
    cout <<"* Egg-----------------------------0.50 *\n";
    cout <<"* Chips---------------------------1.00 *\n";
    cout <<"*                                      *\n";
    cout <<"*                                      *\n";
    cout <<"****************************************\n";
    cout <<"\n\n to select a product please insert the name, and quantity\n";
    cout <<"When done, press the E key for payment\n";
    cin >> Pproduct;
    cin >> Pquantity;
    cout << Pproduct <<" was added to your cart";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You would use a `Map`  or a similar construct for that. This is far too broad of a question in its current form though.

Comment: It sounds like you need a good book, class, or tutorial on data structures and how to represent your idea in a `class` (while a `map` might be a start, what happens when you need to track how many you have to sell or how many have been sold)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an associative container such as [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) instead of `if` statements:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::map<std::string, double> price_map = {{"apple", 0.99},
                                           {"bread", 0.66},
                                           {"cake",1.80}}; 

void foo(const std::string& product)
{
   auto iter = price_map.find(product);
   if (iter != price_map.end())
      std::cout << "The price for " << iter->first << " is " << iter->second << "\n";
   else
      std::cout << "The product named "\" << product << "\" was not found\n";
}

int main()
{
   foo("apple");
   foo("bread");
   foo("beer");
}
```

Output:

```
The price for apple is 0.99
The price for bread is 0.66
The product named "beer" was not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have the products in an array and the prices in a separate array with corresponding subscripts. This way you could create a connection between the two arrays by using the same subscript to display the product and its price.

Comment: Using parallel arrays isn't a good idea when you have alternative options. They're prone to errors if you aren't careful.

Comment: People use parallel arrays when they don't understand more about data structures and how to model their data (i.e. they've only learned about arrays and not `class` or `map`, etc.).